# How can I retrieve the encryption key in this code?

Tags: android, encryption, java, patch-reversing, apk

can anyone explain the following code? is it possible to retrieve the encryption key?
I think the code was heavily obfuscated in addition to obfuscation, I can recognize it is using algorithms like **DESEDE** with *CBC* and *PKCS5Padding* to encrypt http post traffic from the app. my question is does any one know how to retrieve the key here?

```
package c.e.a.a.g;

import a.a;
import android.util.Base64;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class b {

    /* renamed from: a reason: collision with root package name */
    private static volatile b f4799a;

    /* renamed from: b reason: collision with root package name */
    private byte[] f4800b = null;

    /* renamed from: c reason: collision with root package name */
    private String f4801c;

    private b() {
        try {
            this.f4801c = a.a(new byte[]{97, 110, 100, 95, 50, 51, 116, 107, 108, 35, 95, 97, 105, 116, 33}, new byte[]{75, 24, 109, 27, -24, -51, 22, -58, -44, -74, 21, 91, -88, 48, -52, -63, 69, -67, 71, 17, 116, 77, 70, -94, 41, 121, 20, 120, 8, 121, 33, 77});
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.f4800b = e(this.f4801c);
    }

    public static b a() {
        if (f4799a == null) {
            synchronized (b.class) {
                if (f4799a == null) {
                    f4799a = new b();
                }
            }
        }
        return f4799a;
    }

    private final String c(String str) {
        try {
            Cipher instance = Cipher.getInstance("DESEDE/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            instance.init(2, new SecretKeySpec(this.f4800b, "DESede"));
            return a(instance.doFinal(new a().a(str)));
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private final String d(String str) {
        try {
            Cipher instance = Cipher.getInstance("DESEDE/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            instance.init(1, new SecretKeySpec(this.f4800b, "DESede"));
            try {
                return Base64.encodeToString(instance.doFinal(str.getBytes()), 0);
            } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
                return "";
            } catch (BadPaddingException e3) {
                e3.printStackTrace();
                return "";
            }
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e4) {
            e4.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e5) {
            e5.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e6) {
            e6.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private final byte[] e(String str) {
        try {
            return MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e3) {
            e3.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String b(String str) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(str);
        sb.append(b());
        return d(sb.toString());
    }

    private String b() {
        int nextInt = new Random().nextInt(999999);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("|");
        sb.append(nextInt);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String a(String str) {
        return c(str).split(Pattern.quote("|"))[0];
    }

    public b(String str) {
        this.f4800b = e(str);
    }

    private final String a(byte[] bArr) {
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (byte b2 : bArr) {
            stringBuffer.append((char) b2);
        }
        return stringBuffer.toString();
    }
}
```

an example of encrypted http post request produced by this code is like following:

```
{"MobileUsersBE":{"AppVersion":"vB0gg8dKw8/ssTAXDUHLDw==\n","DeviceCode":"NUIDvs43seBumI3SU7Q1R/NWzO0ylo08jPjWcGUxZsFCjEu/IEjcEUYM4V6zswVc\n","DeviceType":"android","GCMCellId":"","Password":"P4fM264BxQXhd3RQu5vk8w==\n","UserName":"i2WZyhFJ9CZTx40Th83siw==\n"},"ServiceUsersBE":{"AppVersion":"ZA+PaD1HcAVZ384ENwEWBw==\n","DeviceCode":"NUIDvs43seBumI3SU7Q1R/NWzO0ylo08jPjWcGUxZsFOFoCbYVotoPrT8YV4yEHL\n","DeviceType":"android","Password":"t1h6/ATZ26VA8nS+fcnvkv0wtPbV8onO\n","TransactionCode":"vfTVe1PFdoFSMOdyYSxAI33cLtBw3z3uUrzOGlZJafQYzgg+Te+n/sDv/nyll3T2","UserName":"N67a2TEuY68jsRadkP0JGrh64aKxVin1\n"}}
```

Comment: With ref. to the code you posted, the key is derived as `md5(this.f4801c)`. You need to find out what the function `a.a` is doing with the two byte arrays.

Comment: hello bro @0xec , I have posted the source code of a.a in here [ https://pastebin.com/L03kwbpj ] , appreciate your help, in some cases in this method code looked like it makes decryption. take a look and i appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The encryption key is stored in the variable `f4800b`. It comes out to the following byte array.

```
43, 57, 97, -68, -63, -61, -40, 9, 50, 87, -104, 101, 63, 34, -78, 60
```

The cipher algorithm used is Triple-DES in ECB mode. It can be decrypted by the following snippet. Note that it requires the BouncyCastle Crypto provider for Java.

```
import java.security.*;
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        byte key[] = new byte[] {43, 57, 97, -68, -63, -61, -40, 9, 50, 87, -104, 101, 63, 34, -78, 60};

        //Base64 encoded cipher text here
        byte ct[] = Base64.getDecoder().decode("i2WZyhFJ9CZTx40Th83siw==");

        Cipher instance = Cipher.getInstance("DESEDE/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        instance.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(key, "DESede"));
        String pt = new String(instance.doFinal(ct));
        System.out.println(pt);
    }
}
```

### Sample output

Using the JSON snippet you provided

```
{
   "MobileUsersBE":{
      "AppVersion":"vB0gg8dKw8/ssTAXDUHLDw==\n",
      "DeviceCode":"NUIDvs43seBumI3SU7Q1R/NWzO0ylo08jPjWcGUxZsFCjEu/IEjcEUYM4V6zswVc\n",
      "DeviceType":"android",
      "GCMCellId":"",
      "Password":"P4fM264BxQXhd3RQu5vk8w==\n",
      "UserName":"i2WZyhFJ9CZTx40Th83siw==\n"
   },
   "ServiceUsersBE":{
      "AppVersion":"ZA+PaD1HcAVZ384ENwEWBw==\n",
      "DeviceCode":"NUIDvs43seBumI3SU7Q1R/NWzO0ylo08jPjWcGUxZsFOFoCbYVotoPrT8YV4yEHL\n",
      "DeviceType":"android",
      "Password":"t1h6/ATZ26VA8nS+fcnvkv0wtPbV8onO\n",
      "TransactionCode":"vfTVe1PFdoFSMOdyYSxAI33cLtBw3z3uUrzOGlZJafQYzgg+Te+n/sDv/nyll3T2",
      "UserName":"N67a2TEuY68jsRadkP0JGrh64aKxVin1\n"
   }
}
```

Shown below are the ciphertexts and the corresponding plaintext to which it decrypts to.

```
vB0gg8dKw8/ssTAXDUHLDw==
2.3|138771
```

```
NUIDvs43seBumI3SU7Q1R/NWzO0ylo08jPjWcGUxZsFCjEu/IEjcEUYM4V6zswVc
8f850645-36ec-350a-8bb3-09c004daeb14|36159
```

```
P4fM264BxQXhd3RQu5vk8w==
test1234|364081
```

```
i2WZyhFJ9CZTx40Th83siw==
test|55664
```

Note that each plain text has a random number appended at the end after the `|` sign. This acts like a salt so that identical plain-texts do not encrypt to the same ciphertext.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105860/discussion-on-answer-by-0xec-how-can-i-retrieve-the-encryption-key-in-this-code).